# How to write text near to image?

Tags: graphics

I want to write text near image, how should I do it(example):

```
|-----|
| pic |- this is text about picture.
|_____|
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use the `InsertBoxL` command from the generic `insbox` macro package. You can choose the number of full length lines before insertion of the graphic file, and if the number of shorter lines is not correct, you change it with an optional argument:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxL{2}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{sendak.png}}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius dapibus metus eget ultrices. Nulla sagittis mauris rutrum, blandit augue eget, laoreet augue. Phasellus enim odio, sagittis in mi sed, fringilla mollis odio. Phasellus quis purus ultricies, tempor purus at, tempus quam. Donec ultricies, ligula ac pretium porttitor, nibh nunc. Integer eros nibh, cursus at est sed, volutpat tristique justo. Donec ornare facilisis lorem, id feugiat elit pellentesque at. Nulla odio mauris, luctus sed faucibus id, dignissim dictum velit. Morbi vehicula velit at massa tristique rhoncus.%

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{sendak.png}}%
Phasellus quis purus ultricies, tempor purus at, tempus quam. Donec ultricies, ligula ac pretium porttitor, nibh nunc. Integer eros nibh, cursus at est sed, volutpat tristique justo. Donec ornare facilisis lorem, id feugiat elit pellentesque at. Nulla odio mauris, luctus sed faucibus id, dignissim dictum velit. Morbi vehicula velit at massa tristique rhoncus.

\InsertBoxL{0}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{sendak.png}}[-1]%
Phasellus quis purus ultricies, tempor purus at, tempus quam. Donec ultricies, ligula ac pretium porttitor, nibh nunc. Integer eros nibh, cursus at est sed, volutpat tristique justo. Donec ornare facilisis lorem, id feugiat elit pellentesque at. Nulla odio mauris, luctus sed faucibus id, dignissim dictum velit. Morbi vehicula velit at massa tristique rhoncus.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since the context was explained now, I think a good solution is to include minipages:

```
\begin{minipage}[l]{width}
 \includegraphics[options]{pic.png}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[r]{width}
 text
\end{minipage}
```

Since these pages align vertically you can be sure, that you write beside the picture in the corresponding minipage. Make sure, that the total width of both minipages is a little less than `1\textwidth` (e.g. 0.45\textwidth for each minipage).

A possibility is the wrapfig package.
[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wrapping_text_around_figures) you can find a good example with source-code.

Basically you need to include the package and then use its environment:

```
\usepackage{wrapfig} % in preamble

% in text
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{gull}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

All the text around it will be wrapped around the picture.

Otherwise you may be thinking of minipages (fixed invisible regions) or columned styles,... You'd need to be more specific what you really need.

Comment: I don't need text all around picture. It is small picture and that picture should be few rows explanation of that picture. And in one page should be about ten parts of pictures/texts

Comment: like danger sign - this is danger sign so keep away from it, because bla bla and bla bla.

Answer (score 2):

When the situation is as easy as in the example, you can proceed as follows:

```
\inlcudegraphics{pic} -- this is text about the picture.
```

Note that for TeX a picture is just a box to set into the line just like text.

For more advanced examples (several lines of text beside the pictue) you can make use of the command `\parbox`.

EDIT: The command `\parbox` has one optional and two required arguments. Its syntax is `\parbox[position]{width}{content}` where position is one of the three letters `bct` (meaning bottom, vertically centered, or top alignment) and width can be given explicitly (e.g. `{1cm}`) or relatively (e.g. `{.8\linewidth}` meaning 80% of the width of the line. A complete example parbox may look like

```
\parbox[c]{.8\linewidth}{-- this is text about the picture.}
```

Comment: So, if there is two or three lines of text near picture I should use \parbox{pic}-- this is text ?

Comment: @Pr0t3: No, you put the text into a parbox that sits besides the box for the picture. It does not harm when you put the picture in a parbox, too, but it is also not necessary.

Comment: Okey. maybe you could tell how in includegraphics I should set my pic size? [Width=0.1] or something other?

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm,keepaspectratio]{Pic/aaa/bal.png} -- \parbox {aaa,bbb and ccc.}` how to use it properly?

Comment: it is writing text near image, but not in middle of image, but bottom, maybe you know how to change it?

Comment: Play around with the optional parameter, try `[t]` instead of `[c]`. You can also put a parbox with an optional placement parameter around the picture to refine placement.

Comment: Do i need to set something in preamble to use \parbox? it is still written in bottom. How to make my parbox work?

Comment: No, `\parbox` is a standard LaTeX command available everywhere.

Comment: Maybe you can see my mistake - `\item[]\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{pic} \parbox[c]{.8\linewidth}{-- text!} `

Comment: It works for me as I expect it to work, but without a complete example document of yours I cannot tell what's going wrong for you.

Comment: It is just a simple documentclass[12pt]{report}, with a items list like: this list contains of {itemize}

Answer (score 1):

Ti*k*z is (almost) always the answer =)  (the image is page 2 of the document obtained)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{mwe} %% to get images
\usepackage{lipsum} %% dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [ampersand replacement=\amp] {
      \node{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}}; \amp \node[text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{text for image 1}; \\
      \node{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}}; \amp \node[text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{text for image 2}; \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]